# how to use getter setter method for search bar in swift 3.1.1?

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchbar, getter-setter

I have implemented search bar in my app. I have a JSON data of some hotels. (name, image, address, mobile number, email). I am getting the name in the search result, but I want to get the entire data of a particular hotel. So, please help me to implement search functionality. I want to use getter setter method. Please help. Thanks in advance!!

```
let str = self.catArr [indexPath.row]
    let url1 = "myapi"
    let url2 = url1+str

    let allowedCharacterSet = (CharacterSet(charactersIn: " ").inverted)
    if let url = url2.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet)
    {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in

            if (responseData.result.value) == nil
            {
                print("Error!!")
            }

            //if (responseData.result.value) != nil
            else
            {
                let response = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                if let resData = response["data"].arrayObject
                {
                    self.arrResponse1 = resData as! [[String: AnyObject]]

                    for item in self.arrResponse1
                    {
                        let name = item["name"] as! String
                        self.arrName.append(name)

                        let add = item["address"] as! String
                        self.arrAddress.append(add)

                        let web = item["website"] as! String
                        self.arrWebsite.append(web)

                        let email = item["email"] as! String
                        self.arrEmail.append(email)

                        let mob = item["mobile"] as! String
                        self.arrMobile.append(mob)

                        let city = item["city"] as! String
                        self.arrCity.append(city)

                        let state = item["state"] as! String
                        self.arrState.append(state)

                        let dist = item["district"] as! String
                        self.arrDistrict.append(dist)

                        let area = item["area"] as! String
                        self.arrArea.append(area)

                        let img = item["image"] as! String
                        self.arrImage.append(img)

                        let rating = item["rating"] as! String
                        self.arrRating.append(rating)

                        let id = item["id"] as! String
                        self.arrId.append(id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    filteredName = self.nameArr.filter({ (String) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = String as NSString
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })

    if(filteredName.count == 0)
    {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    else
    {
        searchActive = true;
        print("Search Array = \(filteredName)")
    }

    self.infoTableView.reloadData()
}
```

//showing in tableview
        if(searchActive)
        {
            cell.lblName.text = self.filteredName [indexPath.row]
        }

```
    else
    {
        let urlImage = str1+self.imageArr [indexPath.row]+".jpg"

        cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlImage), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))
        cell.lblName.text = self.nameArr [indexPath.row]
        cell.lblAddress.text = self.addressArr [indexPath.row]
        cell.lblCity.text = self.cityArr [indexPath.row]
        cell.lblPhone.text = self.mobileArr [indexPath.row]
        cell.lblEmail.text = self.emailArr [indexPath.row]
        cell.lblStar.text = self.ratingArr [indexPath.row]

        cell.phoneString = self.mobileArr [indexPath.row]
        cell.emailString = self.emailArr [indexPath.row]
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code how you are getting this `JSON`` data and how you are displaying in `tableView`

Comment: @NiravD::: using alamofire, I am getting response from json and I am storing it in different arrays and print them row wise in labels in tableview.
self.nameArr is the name array.

Comment: Can you show your some sample `JSON` of your that will give us idea what key you are accessing from `JSON`

Comment: @NiravD
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
                if let JSON = response.result.value{
                    let responseRes = JSON as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    if let resData = responseRes?["data"] as? [AnyObject]{
                        self.arrResponse = resData as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                       for item in self.arrResponse{
                            et name = item["name"] as! String
                            self.arrName.append(name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: Don't add code in comment edit your question and code with it

Comment: Check my below solution

Comment: Have you tried my below solution is it working now ?

Comment: @NiravD one question.
I don't know where to define struct Item{.....} and how do I use it?
and how do I store json response in Item??
I got the else code.
thanks

Comment: you can make one swift file or add any your viewcontroller file before ViewController class decalred

Comment: Also if my answer answers your question consider to mark my answer as accepted if you don't know how to accept answer on Stack Overflow check this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/346600

Comment: everything is fine. just one error is there.
Type 'Item.Type' has no subscript members: in self.id = Item["id"] as? String ?? "Default Id", and
Value of type 'Item' has no member 'content': in $0.content.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)

Comment: Edit your question with code where you are getting this error

Comment: Check the edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having multiple array to store each value what you need is array of custom `class/struct` object and then its easy to use `filter` with it.

```
struct Item { //Make some suitable name 
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let address: String
    let website: String
    let email: String
    let mobile: String
    let city: String
    let state: String
    let district: String
    let area: String
    let image: String
    let rating: String

    init(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? "Default Id"
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? "Default name"
        self.address = dictionary["address"] as? String ?? "Default address"
        self.website = dictionary["website"] as? String ?? "Default website"
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? "Default email"
        self.mobile = dictionary["mobile"] as? String ?? "Default mobile"
        self.city = dictionary["city"] as? String ?? "Default city"
        self.state = dictionary["state"] as? String ?? "Default state"
        self.district = dictionary["district"] as? String ?? "Default district"
        self.area = dictionary["area"] as? String ?? "Default area"
        self.image = dictionary["image"] as? String ?? "Default image"
        self.rating = dictionary["rating"] as? String ?? "Default rating"
    }
}
```

Now you need only two array of type `[Item]` one for normal data and one for `filter` data, so declare two array like this.

```
var items = [Item]()
var filterItems = [Item]()
```

Initialized this `items` array like this way in your `Alamofire` request.

```
let response = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

if let resData = response["data"].arrayObject as? [[String: Any]] {
    self.items = resData.map(Item.init)
}
```

Now use this two array in `tableView` method like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchActive {
         return filterItems.count
    }
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell
    let item = searchActive ? filterItems[indexPath.row] : items[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblName.text = item.name
    cell.lblAddress.text = item.address
    //...Set others detail same way
    return cell
}
```

Now with `textDidChange` filter your `items` array this way.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    filterItems = self.items.filter({ 
         $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) 
    })

    if(filterItems.count == 0) {
        searchActive = false
    }            
    else {
        searchActive = true
        print("Search Array = \(filterItems)")
    }        
    self.infoTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: everything is working fine. Thanks for your help.!!
happy coding.

Comment: @A21 Welcome mate :)